# Differential equation with variation of constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I found an old exam with the the question to solve this differential:

$$y'(x)-2xy(x)=\sinh(x)\cdot e^{x^2} ~~{\rm with}~~ y(0)=0$$

I know that I should probably solve the homogenous part first and then use the method of the variation of the constants to solve for the inhomogenous part.

I do have to start with saying that the $\sinh(x)$ is throwing me off a little and I'm not even sure what the homogenous part is.

Thanks xx

Comment: No need for variation of constants. This is a first-order linear equation, so just find an integrating factor.

Comment: What is the matter with $\sinh$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The homogeneous equation,

$$y'(x)-2xy(x)=0$$

is separable and gives the solution

$$y_h(x)=ce^{x^2}.$$

Now by variation of the constant,

$$y(x)=c(x)e^{x^2}$$

gives

$$c'(x)e^{x^2}+c(x)2xe^{x^2}-2xc(x)e^{x^2}=\sinh(x)e^{x^2}$$

or

$$c'(x)=\sinh(x).$$

The rest is yours.

Answer (score 0):

So we start by solving the homogeneous ODE, i.e

\begin{equation}
y'(x)-2xy(x)=0.
\end{equation}

This can be done by seperation of variables. The above equation is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{dy}{y}=2xdx\\
\iff&\log{\lvert y\rvert}+c=x^2\\
\iff&y_h(x)=ce^{x^2},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Note that the absolute value can be dropped, since the r.h.s. of the equation
\begin{equation}
\lvert y(x) \rvert=De^{x^2}
\end{equation}
is non-negative with $D\geq0$.
Now that we found the homogeneous solution $y_h$, we can obtain the particular solution $y_p$ by  the variation of constants Ansatz:
\begin{equation}
y_p(x)=c(x)e^{x^2}.
\end{equation}
Plugging this into the inhomogenous ODE, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{y_p}'(x)-2xy_p(x)=\sinh{(x)}e^{x^2}\\
\iff&c'(x)e^{x^2}+c(x)2xe^{x^2}-2xc(x)e^{x^2}=\sinh{(x)}e^{x^2}\\
\iff&c'(x)e^{x^2}=\sinh{(x)}e^{x^2}\\
\iff&c'(x)=\sinh{(x)}\\
\iff&c(x)=\cosh{(x)}+\tilde{c},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
with $\tilde{c}\in\mathbb{R}$. So our particular solution reduces to
\begin{equation}
y_p(x)=\left(\cosh{(x)}+\tilde{c}\right)e^{x^2}.
\end{equation}
By linearity of the ODE the general solution can be written as a sum of the homogeneous and particular solution, i.e.
\begin{equation}
y_{gen}(x)=y_h(x)+y_p(x)=ce^{x^2}+\cosh{(x)}e^{x^2}+\tilde{c}e^{x^2}=\left(C+\cosh{(x)}\right)e^{x^2}.
\end{equation}
Inserting the initial condition $y_{gen}(0)=0$, we arrive at
\begin{equation}
y_{gen}(0)=C+1=0 \implies C=-1.
\end{equation}
So the unique solution to your initial value porblem is given by
\begin{equation}
y(x)=e^{x^2}\left( \cosh{(x)}-1\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: THANK YOU!!! xx